# How can I extract and rename specific files from daily compressed zip folders using Python?

Tags: python, shutil, python-os, python-zipfile

Let me preface this by I have never worked with python before but have spent the past several days researching and watching videos. Although I've found solutions that helps with components of this, I'm having a hard time filling in the gaps since it's not the exact situation. I'm not just looking for code, I'm hoping to understand and learn so please provide any resources that would help.

I receive daily compressed zip folders labeled "v1_csv_2022_06_02_2023_etc.zip" within those folders is a sub-folder labeled "export" within the "export" folder contains over 30 csv's. I only care about four of those csv's based on if they have certain keywords in the filename. Ex: only pull csv's that have the keyword "sales", "activity"

The second component of this is when I try to unzip all the files, of course they overwrite and only show the current's day data. I'm assuming based on research this is due to the filenames being the same through each daily compressed zip folder. So I am looking for a way to rename these files and then append them all together. It would be nice to append the zip folder naming convention "2022_06_2023) to the filename. ex: "2022_06_02_2020_sales.csv" end state being 1 master sales csv

Folder Structure
Users -->  username --> documents --> sales & activities --> zip folder (daily zip folders compressed with date in file name) --> export folder ---> 30+ csv files

```
import os
import zipfile

# Path to the directory containing the zip files
zip_directory = '/path/to/zip/files'

# Iterate over all files in the zip directory
for filename in os.listdir(zip_directory):
    if filename.endswith('.zip'):
        # Construct the full path to the zip file
        zip_path = os.path.join(zip_directory, filename)

        # Open the zip file
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
            # Extract all files to a folder named 'export'
            zip_ref.extractall(os.path.join(zip_directory, 'export'))

        # Get the base name of the zip file without the extension
        zip_base_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

        # Iterate over all extracted files in the 'export' folder
        export_directory = os.path.join(zip_directory, 'export')
        for extracted_file in os.listdir(export_directory):
            # Construct the full path to the extracted file
            extracted_file_path = os.path.join(export_directory, extracted_file)

            # Rename the extracted file with the zip file's base name
            new_filename = f'{zip_base_name}_{extracted_file}'
            new_file_path = os.path.join(export_directory, new_filename)
            os.rename(extracted_file_path, new_file_path)
```

I've tried variations of this, but to be honest I've tried a lot of code over the past few days so not sure what's relevant to include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you are extracting, you aren't creating folders based on that extract name. A few things to help:

- First, let's use `pathlib` instead of `os`, it's way more readable for path manipulation
- Second, as you stated you'd like, preserve the naming convention, but let's do that in a folder rather than renaming each individual file

```py
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path

# Path to the directory containing the zip files
zip_directory = Path('/path/to/zip/files')

# Make an exports directory if you want, exist_ok so it
# doesn't throw errors trying to create it twice, and parents
# so you can make some new parent dirs if you want
unload_dir = (
    Path('/path/to/exports')
    .mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
)

# Find all zip files
files = zip_directory.glob('*.zip')

for file in files:
    # take the file name with no extension
    exclusive_name = file.stem

    # mark the new subdirectory
    subdir = unload_dir / exclusive_name
    
    # Make new folder
    subdir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    with zipfile.Zipfile(file, 'r') as zf:
        # extract them to the subdir
        zf.extractall(subdir, 'export')
```

Now the subdirectory has your naming convention, extracting to `/path/to/exports/v1_csv_2022_06_02_2023_etc/*.csv`. The only way it will be overwritten is if you extract the same zip file.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for taking the time to provide that explanation and answer. This was the catalyst I needed, I had to do some altering to the code to accommodate for some other things but got it working. I hope you have a good weekend (: